# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, angular

I work on a site with angular 2 and node.js and I'm try to connect my BDD with a JS script but when I call my script in my html file I've got the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
I'm new in angular 2 and in web but I can't see why I've got this error.
this is my code.

connexionsql.js :

```
        var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : "127.0.0.1",
      user     : "root",
      password : "",
      database : "hope_to"
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT nb_annee_experience FROM annee_experience", function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
      });
    });
```

index.html :

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>HOPE TO</title>
        <base href="/">
        <nav>
          <a href="#"> <img src="C:\wamp64\www\angular2-seed-master\hopetotest.jpg" alt=""> </a>
          |
          <a href="connexion/connexion.html"> Connexion </a>
        </nav>
      </head>

      <body>
        <app>Loading...</app>
        <script async src="main.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="connexionsql.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use require on the frontend, you need to use Browserify:

- http://browserify.org/

> Browserify lets you require('modules') in the browser by bundling up all of your dependencies.

But you are unlikely to be able to connect directly to the database without any backend code for that and even if you could, that would be a very bad idea for many reasons. What is usually done is exposing an API (usually RESTful these days) by your backend that your frontend connects to and it's the backend that has access to the database, not the frontend.

Comment: since this morning I've install browserify but the same error keep comming.
and about exposing my API I have absolutly no idea how to do it.